# PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest Scrape Table from Webpage that Takes a Second to Load?

Tags: powershell, web-scraping, httpwebrequest

I apologize, as I'm not sure how to ask this question properly. I'm trying to scrape a web page using invoke-webrequest, so I can use the data. Normally this is no problem. However, with this page the main section I'm trying to scrape takes a moment to load and then produces what I believe is a table with the data I'm after. When I run my script I get results instantly and it appears to be everything but that section of the page that takes a moment to load.

Is there a way to use this command, have it wait, and scrape that portion of the page with the table?

```
invoke-webrequest -usebasicparsing -usedefaultcredentials -uri http://website.com
```

This appears to be javascript that loads a table with the data. I'm not sure how to scrape the results of the javascript.

Comment: Sounds like part of the page is being loaded by your browser as an ajax request, you'll need to find the correct request and use that instead

Comment: Thank you. Any hints on how I could go about doing what you suggested? I'm still learning. e.g. Find out if it's an ajax request, then request that portion

Comment: You need to use your browser debug tools to watch the network resources that are requested when you load the page

Comment: Any reason why you're using `-UseBasicParsing`?  Might have an impact.

Comment: To be honest, I had used that option previously when scraping a page and it worked. I don't recall the details. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: I'm not able to find anything related to Ajax. I see javascript and asp references. Any idea if it's possible to parse this data?